# Add text at an optional page-break only when breaking occurs

Tags: page-breaking, memoir

I have two tables (created with `tabularx` in the [memoir](/questions/tagged/memoir) class):

```
[ Table 1 ]
[ Table 2 ]
```

They may be adjacent on the same page, or split across two pages like this:

```
[ Table 1 ]
---- page break ----
[ Table 2 ]
```

If and only if a page break occurs between Table 1 and Table 2 I would like to add text of the following sort:

```
[ Table 1 ]
continued on page M
---- page break ----
continued from page N 
[ Table 2 ]
```

I am not sure whether it is relevant that the blocks being split are tables, but I thought to include just in case.

Is this possible in LaTeX? If so, how?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set them both in the same table using `ltxtable` or another package that combines `longtable` and `tabularx`, then longtable can put the continued lines in at the page break by specifying them in the table head and foot.

As noted in comments, if you don't need alignment you can just nest normal `tabularx` (or `\parbox` here) in a `longtable`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}


\begin{longtable}{l}
\endfirsthead
continued from page \thepage
\endhead
continued on next page
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
\fbox{\parbox[t][3cm][c]{2cm}{a table}}\\
\fbox{\parbox[t][4cm][c]{2.5cm}{another table}}
\end{longtable}

\vspace{4cm}

\begin{longtable}{l}
\endfirsthead
continued from page \thepage
\endhead
continued on next page
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
\fbox{\parbox[t][3cm][c]{2cm}{a table}}\\
\fbox{\parbox[t][4cm][c]{2.5cm}{another table}}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sometimes the answer is too easy ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I am not sure `ltxtable` solves the problem, and due to a caveat I cannot use it: First, unless I misunderstand, `LTXtable` seems to be for splitting a single table whereas I have two separate tables. In any case, due to constraints on the system I am using I cannot import an external file with `LTXtable`. Is the solution you proposing to wrap `Table 1` and `Table 2` in a `longtable` environment? That may work. Thanks.

Comment: yes I thought afterwards that just putting two tables in a single column longtable may be simpler for you, if you don't need alignment between the two tables.

Comment: code example added to answer