# Reacting to a page break in LaTeX

Tags: page-breaking

I'm trying to build an environment where if a page breaks in the environment some additional text is automatically printed at the end of the page, while this text is not printed when no page break occurs. So, for example:

```
\begin{special_env}{Please also check following page}
  A lot of text goes here...
  And even more text goes here...
\end{special_env}
```

Should print the text in the environment as normal, but whenever a page break occurs should add "Please also check following page" to the bottom of the page.

I know things like longtable can do this, but my text isn't really a table and I'm not sufficiently advanced in my TeX skills to figure out how they do it. I've seen [Add customized text at an optional page-break](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47303/add-customized-text-at-an-optional-page-break), which almost does what I need except it requires me to already know approximately where the page break will be. I've also seen [Add customized text at an optional page-break](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47303/add-customized-text-at-an-optional-page-break), which again seems to focus too much on tables (unless I'm misunderstanding).

My question is, how can I code this so that it will automatically figure out where the page breaks end up being and inserts the text where needed?

While I have some experience as a LaTeX user and have occasionally ventured into doing some slightly more advanced scripting, my knowledge is really rather limited, so please bear with me while I try to digest your answers.

**[Edit]**

Thanks both for your help. I have played with the different variants proposed, but haven't quite been able to achieve what I need. It's close, but not quite there yet. Let me give you a little bit more detail on what I'm trying to achieve. I am extending a class that defines a question environment for the purposes of writing exam papers. When a question continues on a new page, we're required to add "Question X continues on next page" on that page. The class currently uses an interesting method to determine whether to page break after a question.

A document then consists essentially of a `\maketitle` followed by a sequence of `question` environments, normally with no other text between them.

At the moment, my code looks somewhat like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter

\newif\ifinenv
\inenvfalse

\newcommand \@@footer{\ifinenv {QUESTION \thequestion\ CONTINUES ON NEXT PAGE} \fi}

\def \ps@exam{%
  \let \@mkboth \@gobbletwo%
  \def \@oddhead{}%
  \def \@oddfoot{\@@footer}%
  \def \@evenhead{}%
  \def \@evenfoot{\@@footer}%
}
\pagestyle{exam}

\newcommand \testpagebreak[1]{%
  \vfil%
  \penalty #1%
  \vfilneg%
}

\newcounter{question}

\newenvironment{question}{%
  \refstepcounter{question}%
  \inenvtrue
  \begin{list}{}{}%
      \item[\bf \thequestion.]% 
}{%
  \end{list}%
  \testpagebreak{-350}%
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{question}
    \lipsum[1-7]
  \end{question}

  \begin{question}
    \lipsum[8-13]
  \end{question}

  \begin{question}
    Just a single line

    And another
  \end{question}
\end{document}
```

This works quite well, except where the start of a question is pushed to the start of a new page. In this case, the PTO text will be printed on the page *before* the question starts, so for example:

```
Text of Question 1
Question 2 continues on the next page
----page break----
Text of Question 2
```

Clearly the problem is that the start of the environment of Question 2 is still processed before TeX decides to open a new page. If I replace the `\testpagebreak` code with a hard `\newpage` or leave it out completely all is fine. Is there a way to fiddle with this code to make it work with `\testpagebreak` (or a variant thereof)?

**[/Edit]**

**[Edit 2]**

I've experimented some more based on @Werner's idea. My code can be found at [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/zbAmnkSg). Note that in the second question there are two alternative versions of the contents, a short one and a longer one. Using the short one (so that Question 2 doesn't actually span multiple pages) all is well. Using the long one (so that Question 2 does span multiple pages) the "Question 2 continues" text is shown already on the last page of Question 1; that is one page too early.

From this, I deduce that the label mechanism works correctly. However, the code in the footer doesn't always correctly pick up whether a question actually starts on the page currently being shipped out. I have no idea how to fix this, but maybe someone out there can point me in a useful direction?

**[/Edit 2]**

Many thanks in advance,

Steffen

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Breakable boxes/environments are always a little bit difficult. I would suggest to remove the `See on next page etc.` stuff from the bottom and rather print it at the bottom of the first part of the page-broken environment. You could use `tcolorbox` (with no colours ;-) for breaking such boxes and environments and adding this text at the bottom etc.

Comment: Thanks Christian. I'm not sure I fully understand your suggestion. I need this to print on the bottom of every page that has text from this environment except for the last one. I currently manually insert the text manually once I know where the page breaks are, but that's a little awkward, especially as a document gets edited over time.

Comment: You should show us what you have, perhaps there will be some amendments/suggestions

Comment: What I have is literally just a three step manual process: 1. enter main text and compile to PDF, 2. see whereabouts page breaks occur and add `See on next page` text in approximate location into LaTeX, 3. recompile and keep my fingers crossed.

Comment: Sounds as if you have plenty of time and no other work to do ;-)

Comment: No, I'm working with someone else's class here and am trying to reduce the amount of work I need to do...

Comment: Well, I've to leave my computer now, but perhaps I return to this question later on, unless some other guy attacked the problem already

Comment: Thanks. I've started looking into `tcolorbox` as you recommend, which may indeed help me address the problem.

Comment: Strange, there was a really interesting answer here a moment ago, but now it's gone. @ian-thompson did you delete this again?

Comment: @SteffenZschaler --- I deleted it because it doesn't always change the footer back at the right time. It turns out that it's quite hard to do this; at the end of the environment may be too early (because TeX holds material until it decides on a good location for a page break), but using `\afterpage` as in my solution can make it happen too late.

Comment: @SteffenZschaler --- tried again. Hopefully it works this time.

Comment: Idea: why not simply insure that no page break occurs in the middle of a question?

Comment: Thanks, but some of our questions require quite a bit of expose and the odd figure, so don't necessarily fit on a single page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about the following idea?

It's much different from yours (or perhaps the class author's), but perhaps more robust as it uses the `\label`-`\ref` system to determine whether a page break has occurred mid-question:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paper=a5paper,margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{multido}% Just for this example
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}% Just for this example
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\newcounter{question}

\newenvironment{question}{%
    \begin{list}{}{}%
      \refstepcounter{question}%
      \item[\bfseries\thequestion.]%
      \leavevmode% Start paragraph
      \label{question-start-\thequestion}%
  }{%
    \label{question-end-\thequestion}%
    \end{list}
  }

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyfoot[L]{% Left footer
  \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{question-start-\thequestion}<\getpagerefnumber{question-end-\thequestion}
    Question~\thequestion{} continues on the next page%
  \fi}
\fancyfoot[R]{See next page}% Right footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule

\AtEndDocument{\fancyfoot[R]{}}% Remove right footer at end of document

\sloppypar% Just for this example
\begin{document}

\multido{\i=1+1}{50}{%
  \begin{question}
    \lipsum[\i]
  \end{question}
  \bigskip
}

\end{document}
```

At each `\item` inside `question`, a `\label` is set, and then another `\label` at the end of the `question`. A check is made to see whether the page number at the start is different from (less than) the ending page number. Accordingly, the footer sets the appropriate clause.

Comment: Thanks, this looks very interesting indeed. I'll give it a spin once back at my main computer and report back.

Comment: I've now tried this. Unfortunately, it suffers from the same problem as my attempts in the edits above: when the open label is created, TeX hasn't necessarily decided yet whether to move the start of the question onto a new page, so in those cases I get the text a page too early.

Comment: @SteffenZschaler: Retry with the minor addition of `\leavevmode`...

Comment: Thanks, @werner. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to make any difference at all. I'm not sure I fully understand how `\leavevmode` works, but I couldn't figure out why it would help.

Comment: @SteffenZschaler: It should start the setting of the list item before setting the label.

Comment: Thanks @werner. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to do this. What's the protocol on this site, am I allowed to add an answer to my own question? If so, I could use this to attach the result I'm currently seeing. Maybe you or someone else would be able to figure out what's going on...

Comment: @SteffenZschaler: The answer section is for *answers*. If you have an ongoing problem using one of the solution proposed, you can either edit your own post to show the "current state that still highlights some problem" or post content to [Pastebin.org](http://pastebin.com/)...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of protocol, @werner. I have added the results of some more experimentation to the original question using a pastebin link to keep things reasonably compact.

Comment: @SteffenZschaler: I see you've mixed in your `\testpagebreak` with my construction. I think That's wrong. Why do you use or need `\testpagebreak`? Is it because you need to leave a specific amount of space at the bottom of a page blank? Or perhaps because you need space left blank after a question? In that regard, one could also use [`needspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace). Regardless, I'm not entirely clear on the need for using `\testpagebreak`.

Comment: `\testpagebreak` is what the current class uses to determine whether or not to start a new page after a question (and, in fact, after sub-questions etc.). I believe it is an attempt to balance readability in exam conditions (ideally every question on one page) with wasting paper (ideally, all questions on one page). I don't like it very much, but am trying to resolve one issue at a time. `needspace` looks like it might give me a better way of expressing the above intention, so I'll have a play to see if it also fixes the problem with the PTO text.

Comment: Excellent. This has worked. I have had to combine it with the `\inenv` idea from @ian-thompson to ensure it doesn't print the PTO on the final page of a question (see [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/VEdCbu1u)). Many thanks, @werner.

Answer (score 1):

My original idea was to change the footer at the environment start and
revert it at the end, but this fails if the environment ends whilst
TeX is storing material that will ultimately contain a page break
(most likely if the environment end ends up near the top of a page).

I think the right way to do this is to put a switch in the footer
itself, to detect whether or not the environment is active when the
page is constructed. I've used the [fancyhdr package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) because it makes
changing the footer very easy, but it isn't strictly necessary.
Similarly, I've used the [geometry package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) to adjust the page
dimensions and move the end of the environment from place to
place, but this is just for testing purposes. Finally, note that there
is no need to execute `\inenvfalse` at the end of the environment,
because `\inenvtrue` is local, and the global setting is restored at
`\end{myenv}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[width=16cm,height=20cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum} % For dummy text
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\newif\ifinenv
\inenvfalse
\newcommand\myrfoot{\ifinenv PTO \else Hello! \fi}
\rfoot\myrfoot

\newenvironment{myenv}
{\section*{Environment start!}\inenvtrue}
{\par\medskip\noindent\centering\rule{0.75\textwidth}{2pt}\par\bigskip}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-8]
\begin{myenv}
\lipsum[9-16]
\end{myenv}
\lipsum[17-24]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @ian-thompson. This almost fixes it, but one problem remains (see my edits to my original post). Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks, Steffen

Comment: @SteffenZschaler --- I'll think about this, but won't have time until tomorrow.