# \ifthenelse atomic proposition not behaving as expected when paired with fancy footer

Tags: hyperref, conditionals, ifthenelse

I understand that the title of the thread is a bit cryptic, but I admit that I don't have much of a clue about the reason for which this (apparently simple) conditional (sometimes) fails in working as it should.

This issue is to a certain extent an extension of [this old thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/690567/have-something-appear-in-the-footer-only-if-section-isnt-over), where the main part of the code I'm working on was suggested. The issue, though, is very different from the one I proposed in the original thread, so I thought to do a new one, for clarity.

Here's my MWE. It's not so short because I didn't use `\lipsum`: I needed, as you'll see, a precise control over where, exactly, LaTeX was putting a pagebreak. Consider all the italian text here, to all extent, as lipsum-like gibberish.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{book}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[paperwidth=21cm, paperheight=29.7cm, heightrounded, text={15cm, 23.7cm}, centering]{geometry}   
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

% Sets counter
\newcounter{currentparagraph}

% Sets environment "paragrafo", that places labels at the beginnings and ends of each section
\newenvironment{paragrafo}{%
    \label{text-begin-\thecurrentparagraph}%
}{%
    \label{text-end-\thecurrentparagraph}%
}

% Sets fancy
\frenchspacing
\setactivedoublequote
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{4pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[RO]{\small \thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\small \thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\textit{Profanator}}
\fancyhead[CO]{\textit{Atlante}}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{%
    % If, according to the "currentparagraph" counter, the last paragraph ends in a different page from which it started this will print a "Continua..." text at the right bottom of the page
    \ifthenelse{%
        \getpagerefnumber{text-begin-\thecurrentparagraph} < \getpagerefnumber{text-end-\thecurrentparagraph}%
    }{%
        \color{lightgray}\textit{Continua...}%
    }%
    {}%
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{currentparagraph}{1}
\section*{\centering 1}
\begin{paragrafo}
    
\pageref{text-begin-\thecurrentparagraph}
\pageref{text-end-\thecurrentparagraph}

Sei un poveraccio. Un paria, un barbone, un reietto. La società non ti desidera, oppure sei tu a non desiderarla. I motivi per cui la situazione è questa possono essere i più disparati, e i dettagli non c'importano. Sta di fatto che tu rifuggi la civiltà.

Il mondo attorno a te si coccola in un rassicurante gioco di potere e denaro a cui tu non senti di appartenere. Mentre le persone attorno a te lottavano tra di loro, cibandosi l'uno dell'altro per tentare di trionfare o soccombere, tu hai fatto un passo di lato. Hai lasciato alle tue spalle un mondo che hai giudicato autoreferenziale, in cui sapevi che non avresti mai potuto essere felice. E così facendo hai abbracciato la \textit{vita}.

La \textit{vita} è quella del profanatore. Così chiamano quelli come te, che vivono ai margini nutrendosi di ciò che riescono a recuperare dalle rovine del passato. Cripte, edifici abbandonati, sotterranei infestati sono luoghi che la gente normale aborre. Per quelli come te, invece, sono un'opportunità. Essi nascondono potenziali ricchezze: oggetti d'arte, testi perduti, segreti che la cosiddetta civiltà, in realtà, desidera. E tu allora sei quello che affronta i misteri di queste rovine, cercando questi frutti della terra per rivenderli al miglior offerente, in cambio di denaro, di un pasto caldo, di un tetto sulla testa.

A tuo modo, anche se la società si rifuta di accettarlo, pure tu hai una funzione in questo mondo. Sei un profanatore. Questa è la tua \textit{vita}.

Vai al \textbf{14}.
\end{paragrafo}

\setcounter{currentparagraph}{465}
\section*{\centering 465}
\begin{paragrafo}

\pageref{text-begin-\thecurrentparagraph}
\pageref{text-end-\thecurrentparagraph}

Per quanto si tratti di un fatato, il tanuki resta un cane, e necessariamente cadrà nelle trappole come qualsiasi cane. Ti basterà costruirne una. Per quanto si tratti di un fatato, il tanuki resta un cane, e necessariamente cadrà nelle trappole come qualsiasi cane. Ti basterà costruirne una.

Guardandoti attorno giudichi che l'opzione migliore sia fare una buca, dentro cui attirarlo depositando del cibo di suo interesse. Ti metti quindi al lavoro, scavando nel corso di oltre tre ore una buca circolare, larga due metri e profonda altrettanto. Dovrebbe essere sufficiente per trattenere il tanuki quanto basta che permetterti di catturarlo.

Ti aggrappi con le mani al bordo della fossa, mentre tiri il fiato. Ormai la buca è scavata: fra poco si tratterà solo di aspettare. Dopo qualche istante tuttavia hai la sensazione che dell'aria umida ti stia sfiorando le dita della mano. Un attimo più tardi qualcosa te la sberlecca. La ritrai immediatamente, alzando lo sguardo verso il bordo della fossa, temendo il peggio.

E invece ciò che ti osserva da sopra la buca è proprio il tanuki. Il muso da canide, caratterizzato da un pelo con la stessa colorazione della tipica mascherina del procione, ti scruta con profondità, curiosità e un pizzico di derisione. Giureresti che stia sorridendo. Resti come inebetito per qualche secondo. Il gioco si è capovolto: tu sei nella buca, lui è fuori. Rinvieni di colpo e ti tuffi verso di esso, cercando di afferrarlo per una zampa, ma lui è più lesto e balza all'indietro. Ti tiri fuori dalla fossa in un attimo, ma il tanuki è comunque più veloce e con una serie di piccoli grugniti, che sembrano una risata divertita, si mette a correre lungo il declivio della collina, per nulla rallentanto dal gigantesco scroto che, così come raccontano le favole, si trascina tra le gambe.

Ti aggrappi con le mani al bordo della fossa, mentre tiri il fiato. Ormai la buca è scavata: fra poco si tratterà solo di aspettare. Dopo qualche istante tuttavia hai la sensazione che dell'aria umida ti stia sfiorando le dita della mano. Un attimo più tardi qualcosa te la sberlecca. La ritrai immediatamente, alzando lo sguardo verso il bordo della fossa, temendo il peggio. La ritrai immediatamente, alzando lo sguardo verso il bordo della fossa, temendo il peggio. La ritrai immediatamente, alzando lo sguardo verso il bordo della fossa, temendo il peggio. La ritrai immediatamente, alzando lo sguardo verso il bordo della fossa, temendo il peggio.

Vai al \textbf{472}.
\end{paragrafo}

\setcounter{currentparagraph}{466}
\section*{\centering 466}
\begin{paragrafo}
    
\pageref{text-begin-\thecurrentparagraph}
\pageref{text-end-\thecurrentparagraph}

Ti muovi lungo il declivio, cercando di fare meno rumore possibile e prestando attenzione a ogni piccolo segnale che possa suggerire la presenza di questo tanuki. Impronte, carcasse, ruggiti: ti aspetti il peggio, perciò vai alla ricerca di qualsiasi cosa che sia fuori posto rispetto all'ambiente circostante.

Dopo qualche minuto le tue orecchie vengono raggiunte da un battere ritmico, come di piccoli tamburi. Che tu non sia solo? Facendoti ancora più circospetto ti avvii, un passo alla volta, verso la fonte di quel suono. Sarebbe molto appropriato, per un tengu, far convergere nello stesso luogo più persone, dicendo loro di cercare qualcosa che non esiste.

E invece il tanuki esiste. Quando superi un cespuglio ti ritrovi a pochi metri da una figura simile a un cane di dimensioni medio-piccole, con il manto simile a quello di un procione, seduto a terra. Di fronte a sè esso tiene nientemeno che il proprio stesso scroto, voluminosissimo rispetto alla mole dell'animale, ed è intento a battere le sue zampe anteriori sopra di esso, usando i propri testicoli come veri e propri tamburi. Tiene lo sguardo rivolto verso l'alto e la lingua fuori, beato, come se fosse intento a suonare chissà che melodia.

Non c'è dubbio che si tratti di un fatto. Senza lasciarti dominare dalla perplessità balzi in avanti, afferrando il tanuki per la collottola e sollevandolo da terra prima che esso possa reagire.

Vai al \textbf{471}.
\end{paragrafo}

\setcounter{currentparagraph}{467}
\section*{\centering 467}
\begin{paragrafo}

\pageref{text-begin-\thecurrentparagraph}
\pageref{text-end-\thecurrentparagraph}

Segna un fallimento di Esplorazione. Se avevi fatto appello alla tua Natura dimezzane il valore arrotondando per eccesso.

Provi a figurarti questo tanuki. Ti immagini una bestia dalle fattezze inumane, forse vicine a quelle del tengu. Un qualcosa di piumato, di color rosso e con un grosso naso. Sicuramente dev'essere qualcosa di pericoloso, come tutte le porcherie che sfuggono al regno dei fatati. Stringi i denti e, con determinazione, cominci a esplorare il declivio, scustando i cespugli con attenzione, pronto a tutto.

Mentre, con il cuore in gola, procedi con il tuo ingrato compito, non ti fai distrarre da nulla. Allontani le zanzare con uno schiaffo, non degni di uno sguardo gli uccellini che vivono tra questi cespugli, e non presti nemmeno attenzione a un piccolo cane solitario, un randagio lungo poco oltre il mezzo metro che, curioso, si avvicina a te chiedendo una carezza, o più probabilmente del cibo.

Quest'ultimo si unisce a te nella tua ricerca del tanuki. Anche se tu lo ignori lui comprende che sei alla ricerca di qualcosa e quindi ti segue, mettendosi a perlustrare a sua volta i cespugli attorno a te, mano a mano che li esplori.

Dopo due ore abbondanti hai controllato tutti i cespugli di questo declivio. Di questo terribile fatato non c'è traccia. Che si sia nascosto sotto terra? Forse l'erba nasconde delle buche. Mentre ci pensi accarezzi il cane, che si posizionato vicino alla tua gamba.

Che strano, un cane così ben educato, in mezzo al niente. Lo osservi ora camminare tra i cespuglietti, cercando qualcosa da mangiare, trascinandosi dietro il suo voluminosissimo scroto, così grande da strisciare sul terreno.

Un momento. Un cane con uno scroto gigante? Non può essere normale.

Di colpo, la realizzazione. È lui il tanuki!

Trattenendo il fiato corri dietro al cane, tentando di afferrarlo. Questo però capisce a sua volta, di colpo, che era lui che stavi cercando. Appena ti vede correre esso si mette a correre ben più veloce di te, nonostante il suo ingombrante fardello, lungo il declivio erboso che hai esplorato per tutto questo tempo.

Vai a \textbf{472}.

Trattenendo il fiato corri dietro al cane, tentando di afferrarlo. Questo però capisce a sua volta, di colpo, che era lui che stavi cercando. Appena ti vede correre esso si mette a correre ben più veloce di te, nonostante il suo ingombrante fardello, lungo il declivio erboso che hai esplorato per tutto questo tempo.
\end{paragrafo}

\end{document}
```

The document part is generated by an other script, and basically contains hundreds of paragraphs of various length. Such paragraphs' number and order will be randomized, so I won't have control over where exactly each paragraph will end up.

What the `\paragrafo` command does is to place labels, numbered with the section number, at the beginning and end of each section.

At the end of every page `\fancyhdr` uses these labels to check if the last sections begins and ends in the same page. If not, it prints a line ("Continua..."), in light gray, at the bottom right of the page.

Ignore the fact that it's printing it also at the end of the last page. That happens because, for the sake of the MWE, I removed other parts of the code.

This works without a hassle 99% of times. The remaining 1% of times are cases such as this. Run that code and you'll see that, at the end of page 1, it won't print anything.

[image: page 1]

[image: page 2]

[image: page 3]

Try to add a few line to section 465 and you'll see that the "Continua..." line will appear.

I set every section in such a way that, in the first line, it prints the page numbers of the pages in which `\section*` begins and ends. These are precisely the two numbers that are confronted in the fancy conditional. As you see, in section 465 LaTeX correctly says that the section starts in page 1 and ends in page 2. And yet it doesn't print the line.

This usually (albeit not necessarily) happens in cases such as this MWE: a single line or two, either a new paragraph or a part of the last paragraph ending up in the following page. It never happens when there's a big block of text (as you see in section 467).

Any idea about what could be causing the problem?

**EDIT 10/03/2024**

Now that I know what the issue is, I changed the title to something more specific, so that it's easier to find in case somebody in the future looks for a solution to a similar issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the page is shipped out a little bit more is already typeset. Basically, think of it as the system typesetting a block of text and then inserting the page break. So it prepares a block a bit longer than the available space, splits it, ships out the page and then starts the next page with the remainder. So when the page ships out, the paragraph is already finished and the next begun.

What this means is that when the first page ships out, `\thecurrentparagraph` is not 465, but 466. So the numbers compared are 2 and 2 and no continuation label is typeset. To see this, modify your code something like the following and compile at the terminal. This will show you three values: 466 for the first page and 467 for the second and third. So the different labels for 465 are never even examined.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\showmethis{\showthe\c@currentparagraph}
\makeatother
\fancyfoot[R]{%
    % If, according to the "currentparagraph" counter, the last paragraph ends in a different page from which it started this will print a "Continua..." text at the right bottom of the page
    \showmethis
    \ifthenelse{%
        \pageref{text-begin-\thecurrentparagraph} < \pageref{text-end-\thecurrentparagraph}%
    }{%
        \color{lightgray}\textit{Continua...}%
    }%
    {}%
}
```

This is why 'dictionary-style headers' are tricky. To reliably put this kind of information into headers/footers, you need to use *marks*, as explained in `fancyhdr`'s documentation. One of the sections explains how to use `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` to create 'dictionary-style' headers. That's approximately what you want to do.

Unfortunately, `fancyhdr` doesn't mention that this will not work correctly if you're using Babel with active characters. In this case, Babel uses `\rightmark` to re-activate those characters on each page, so `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` are never equal or, indeed, comparable.

That means we need the section on `fancyhdr`'s sister package, `extramarks`. In fact, this greatly simplifies things and there is even an example showing how to produce continuation markers. That layout is more complex than yours and we only really need a single mark. This also solves the problem on the final page, so whatever code you have to manage this specifically isn't needed.

Basically, we set a mark each time we start one of the custom sections and we clear it each time we finish. If the section hasn't ended when the page ends, the mark has content; if it has, the mark is empty. So all we need do is use the mark in the relevant footer. No need to compare anything.

I've also taken `\centering` out of the `\section*{}` commands because this shouldn't be there. Markup should be separate from content. Including it in the names of sections will also complicate things if you want a table of contents or hyperlinks. Instead of using `\centering` in each `\section*{}`, we use `\sectionc*{}`. `\sectionc` and `\sectionc*` are simple variants of `\section` and `\section*`. The only difference is that they centre the section title, whereas the standard pair do not.

`paragrafo` now takes an optional argument. If the argument is omitted, the counter is simply incremented and used for the title of the section. If the argument is given, the counter is set to the given value and used for the title. This environment also takes care of the marks for the continuation labels.

You may also want to include `italian` in your class options so other packages pick it up.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{book}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/712415/ addaswyd o gwestiwn il mietitore: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/712411/
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[paperwidth=21cm, paperheight=29.7cm, heightrounded, text={15cm, 23.7cm}, centering]{geometry}   
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{extramarks}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

% Sets counter
\newcounter{currentparagraph}
% Sets environment "paragrafo", that places labels at the beginnings and ends of each section
\NewDocumentEnvironment {paragrafo} {o} {%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \setcounter{currentparagraph}{#1}%
  }{%
    \stepcounter{currentparagraph}%
  }%
  \ExpandArgs {Ne} \sectionc*{\thecurrentparagraph}%
  \extramarks{}{\textit{Continua\dots{}}}%
  \label{text-begin-\thecurrentparagraph}%
}{%
  \label{text-end-\thecurrentparagraph}%
  \extramarks{}{}%
}
% Sets fancy
\frenchspacing
\setactivedoublequote
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{4pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[RO]{\small \thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\small \thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\textit{Profanator}}
\fancyhead[CO]{\textit{Atlante}}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\lastxmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\sectionc{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
  {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\centering}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  
\begin{paragrafo}[1]
    
\pageref{text-begin-\thecurrentparagraph}
\pageref{text-end-\thecurrentparagraph}

Sei un poveraccio. Un paria, un barbone, un reietto. La società non ti desidera, oppure sei tu a non desiderarla. I motivi per cui la situazione è questa possono essere i più disparati, e i dettagli non c'importano. Sta di fatto che tu rifuggi la civiltà.

Il mondo attorno a te si coccola in un rassicurante gioco di potere e denaro a cui tu non senti di appartenere. Mentre le persone attorno a te lottavano tra di loro, cibandosi l'uno dell'altro per tentare di trionfare o soccombere, tu hai fatto un passo di lato. Hai lasciato alle tue spalle un mondo che hai giudicato autoreferenziale, in cui sapevi che non avresti mai potuto essere felice. E così facendo hai abbracciato la \textit{vita}.

La \textit{vita} è quella del profanatore. Così chiamano quelli come te, che vivono ai margini nutrendosi di ciò che riescono a recuperare dalle rovine del passato. Cripte, edifici abbandonati, sotterranei infestati sono luoghi che la gente normale aborre. Per quelli come te, invece, sono un'opportunità. Essi nascondono potenziali ricchezze: oggetti d'arte, testi perduti, segreti che la cosiddetta civiltà, in realtà, desidera. E tu allora sei quello che affronta i misteri di queste rovine, cercando questi frutti della terra per rivenderli al miglior offerente, in cambio di denaro, di un pasto caldo, di un tetto sulla testa.

A tuo modo, anche se la società si rifuta di accettarlo, pure tu hai una funzione in questo mondo. Sei un profanatore. Questa è la tua \textit{vita}.

Vai al \textbf{14}.
\end{paragrafo}

\begin{paragrafo}[465]

\pageref{text-begin-\thecurrentparagraph}
\pageref{text-end-\thecurrentparagraph}

Per quanto si tratti di un fatato, il tanuki resta un cane, e necessariamente cadrà nelle trappole come qualsiasi cane. Ti basterà costruirne una. Per quanto si tratti di un fatato, il tanuki resta un cane, e necessariamente cadrà nelle trappole come qualsiasi cane. Ti basterà costruirne una.

Guardandoti attorno giudichi che l'opzione migliore sia fare una buca, dentro cui attirarlo depositando del cibo di suo interesse. Ti metti quindi al lavoro, scavando nel corso di oltre tre ore una buca circolare, larga due metri e profonda altrettanto. Dovrebbe essere sufficiente per trattenere il tanuki quanto basta che permetterti di catturarlo.

Ti aggrappi con le mani al bordo della fossa, mentre tiri il fiato. Ormai la buca è scavata: fra poco si tratterà solo di aspettare. Dopo qualche istante tuttavia hai la sensazione che dell'aria umida ti stia sfiorando le dita della mano. Un attimo più tardi qualcosa te la sberlecca. La ritrai immediatamente, alzando lo sguardo verso il bordo della fossa, temendo il peggio.

E invece ciò che ti osserva da sopra la buca è proprio il tanuki. Il muso da canide, caratterizzato da un pelo con la stessa colorazione della tipica mascherina del procione, ti scruta con profondità, curiosità e un pizzico di derisione. Giureresti che stia sorridendo. Resti come inebetito per qualche secondo. Il gioco si è capovolto: tu sei nella buca, lui è fuori. Rinvieni di colpo e ti tuffi verso di esso, cercando di afferrarlo per una zampa, ma lui è più lesto e balza all'indietro. Ti tiri fuori dalla fossa in un attimo, ma il tanuki è comunque più veloce e con una serie di piccoli grugniti, che sembrano una risata divertita, si mette a correre lungo il declivio della collina, per nulla rallentanto dal gigantesco scroto che, così come raccontano le favole, si trascina tra le gambe.

Ti aggrappi con le mani al bordo della fossa, mentre tiri il fiato. Ormai la buca è scavata: fra poco si tratterà solo di aspettare. Dopo qualche istante tuttavia hai la sensazione che dell'aria umida ti stia sfiorando le dita della mano. Un attimo più tardi qualcosa te la sberlecca. La ritrai immediatamente, alzando lo sguardo verso il bordo della fossa, temendo il peggio. La ritrai immediatamente, alzando lo sguardo verso il bordo della fossa, temendo il peggio. La ritrai immediatamente, alzando lo sguardo verso il bordo della fossa, temendo il peggio. La ritrai immediatamente, alzando lo sguardo verso il bordo della fossa, temendo il peggio.

Vai al \textbf{472}.
\end{paragrafo}

\begin{paragrafo}
    
\pageref{text-begin-\thecurrentparagraph}
\pageref{text-end-\thecurrentparagraph}

Ti muovi lungo il declivio, cercando di fare meno rumore possibile e prestando attenzione a ogni piccolo segnale che possa suggerire la presenza di questo tanuki. Impronte, carcasse, ruggiti: ti aspetti il peggio, perciò vai alla ricerca di qualsiasi cosa che sia fuori posto rispetto all'ambiente circostante.

Dopo qualche minuto le tue orecchie vengono raggiunte da un battere ritmico, come di piccoli tamburi. Che tu non sia solo? Facendoti ancora più circospetto ti avvii, un passo alla volta, verso la fonte di quel suono. Sarebbe molto appropriato, per un tengu, far convergere nello stesso luogo più persone, dicendo loro di cercare qualcosa che non esiste.

E invece il tanuki esiste. Quando superi un cespuglio ti ritrovi a pochi metri da una figura simile a un cane di dimensioni medio-piccole, con il manto simile a quello di un procione, seduto a terra. Di fronte a sè esso tiene nientemeno che il proprio stesso scroto, voluminosissimo rispetto alla mole dell'animale, ed è intento a battere le sue zampe anteriori sopra di esso, usando i propri testicoli come veri e propri tamburi. Tiene lo sguardo rivolto verso l'alto e la lingua fuori, beato, come se fosse intento a suonare chissà che melodia.

Non c'è dubbio che si tratti di un fatto. Senza lasciarti dominare dalla perplessità balzi in avanti, afferrando il tanuki per la collottola e sollevandolo da terra prima che esso possa reagire.

Vai al \textbf{471}.
\end{paragrafo}

\begin{paragrafo}

\pageref{text-begin-\thecurrentparagraph}
\pageref{text-end-\thecurrentparagraph}

Segna un fallimento di Esplorazione. Se avevi fatto appello alla tua Natura dimezzane il valore arrotondando per eccesso.

Provi a figurarti questo tanuki. Ti immagini una bestia dalle fattezze inumane, forse vicine a quelle del tengu. Un qualcosa di piumato, di color rosso e con un grosso naso. Sicuramente dev'essere qualcosa di pericoloso, come tutte le porcherie che sfuggono al regno dei fatati. Stringi i denti e, con determinazione, cominci a esplorare il declivio, scustando i cespugli con attenzione, pronto a tutto.

Mentre, con il cuore in gola, procedi con il tuo ingrato compito, non ti fai distrarre da nulla. Allontani le zanzare con uno schiaffo, non degni di uno sguardo gli uccellini che vivono tra questi cespugli, e non presti nemmeno attenzione a un piccolo cane solitario, un randagio lungo poco oltre il mezzo metro che, curioso, si avvicina a te chiedendo una carezza, o più probabilmente del cibo.

Quest'ultimo si unisce a te nella tua ricerca del tanuki. Anche se tu lo ignori lui comprende che sei alla ricerca di qualcosa e quindi ti segue, mettendosi a perlustrare a sua volta i cespugli attorno a te, mano a mano che li esplori.

Dopo due ore abbondanti hai controllato tutti i cespugli di questo declivio. Di questo terribile fatato non c'è traccia. Che si sia nascosto sotto terra? Forse l'erba nasconde delle buche. Mentre ci pensi accarezzi il cane, che si posizionato vicino alla tua gamba.

Che strano, un cane così ben educato, in mezzo al niente. Lo osservi ora camminare tra i cespuglietti, cercando qualcosa da mangiare, trascinandosi dietro il suo voluminosissimo scroto, così grande da strisciare sul terreno.

Un momento. Un cane con uno scroto gigante? Non può essere normale.

Di colpo, la realizzazione. È lui il tanuki!

Trattenendo il fiato corri dietro al cane, tentando di afferrarlo. Questo però capisce a sua volta, di colpo, che era lui che stavi cercando. Appena ti vede correre esso si mette a correre ben più veloce di te, nonostante il suo ingombrante fardello, lungo il declivio erboso che hai esplorato per tutto questo tempo.

Vai a \textbf{472}.

Trattenendo il fiato corri dietro al cane, tentando di afferrarlo. Questo però capisce a sua volta, di colpo, che era lui che stavi cercando. Appena ti vede correre esso si mette a correre ben più veloce di te, nonostante il suo ingombrante fardello, lungo il declivio erboso che hai esplorato per tutto questo tempo.
\end{paragrafo}

\tableofcontents

\sectionc*{Centred unnumbered section without \texttt{paragrafo}}

\sectionc*{No optional argument for starred centred section}

\sectionc[CNSWP]{Centred numbered section without \texttt{paragrafo}}

\sectionc{Another section similar to the prior one}

\section[short title]{Long title}

\section{Common title}

\section*{Common unnumbered section}

\section*{No optional argument for starred section by default}

\end{document}
```

[image: marks for continuation in footer]

The following demonstrates the difference between the two sets of commands outside `paragrafo`. I put the table of contents on the last page to check the optional arguments of `\section` and `\sectionc` behaved as expected, without messing up the sample continuation marks.

[image: examples of \section, \section*, \sectionc and \sectionc* outside paragrafo]

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you: I would have never found the solution alone, I was checking this code since a few days... Besides: there's a minor problem with the new definition of \section: I actually need only the \section* to be centered, while \section should be left aligned as usual. I'm trying to tinker with your code but I don't understand how to set that. How can I achieve it?

Comment: @ilmietitore Do you want to use `\section*` vs. `\section` for this or would you rather have an alternative such as `\sectionc*` for the centred ones? If you did that, you could still use `\section*` if you wanted and it wouldn't require the title to always be the counter number, but it would obviously require another command.

Comment: @ilmietitore And, yes, the *marks* stuff is weird. I just happened to remember `fancyhdr` had stuff on this because I've seen questions about dictionary headers. It's the kind of thing you could stare at your code for days and not figure out the problem unless you check just the right thing, because there isn't a problem with the code really. (At least, if you're like me --- my assumption is always that my code is the problem. Generally, that's an accurate assumption in my case, but it's not true for you here. The code does exactly what you expect. Just TeX doesn't.)

Comment: a command such as a \sectionc that behaves exactly like a \section* but is centered would be perfect.

Comment: @ilmietitore Please see edited code above. `\sectionc*` behaves like `\section*` and `\sectionc` behaves like `\section` except that, in both cases, they are centred. It's easier to make a pair than set up a `\sectionc` which behaves like the starred version, though the latter is possible if required.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very much