How to efficiently reference starred sections in bookmarks
In the book I'm writing I make a lot of use of \chapter*, \section*, \subsection* and so on. I want those sections to appear in the PDF boomarks, though. And here I am, two days later, still trying to figure out how to do that efficiently.
The closer result I was able to produce is this, using package nameref.
As you'll see I'm using the command \metadef to produce a starred version of \chapter that behaves exactly like \chapter* but with the added bonus of the bookmark.
The code for that comes from this other answer.
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Creates \metadef, a command used to better manage starred sectioning commands
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\metadef}[1]{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand#1{%
        \@ifstar{\csname s\string#1\endcsname}{\csname n\string#1\endcsname}%
    }%
    \edef\meta@def@name{\string#1}%
    \meta@def
}
\newcommand\meta@def[3][0]{%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname n\meta@def@name\endcsname[#1]{#2}%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname s\meta@def@name\endcsname[#1]{#3}%
}
\makeatother

% Creates \chapterplus, a command that, if not starred, acts like \chapter, and, if starred, acts like \chapter* but adds the entry to the bookmarks
\metadef{\chapterplus}[1]{\chapter{#1}}{\pdfbookmark{#1}{#1}\chapter*{#1}}

\begin{document}

\chapterplus*{Chapter one}
\lipsum[1-2]

\chapterplus{Chapter two}
\lipsum[3-4]

\chapterplus*{Chapter three}
\lipsum[5-6]

\end{document}

If you try this you'll see that the generated PDF will have a bookmark set for every chapter:

the bookmark to chapter 1 works;
the bookmark to chapter 2 works (it is generated normally by \chapter);
the bookmark to chapter 3 works but points to the end of the previous page.

I suppose this means that the anchor is being set in the place in which I'm calling \chapter*, and THEN the page is broken; the chapter name is thus generated one, if not two pages later.
Since \chapter is able to produce a working bookmark I suppose that there must be a way around this problem.
I tried to use this other solution, involving the use of the package bookmark, but the result is exactly the same.
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Creates \metadef, a command used to better manage starred sectioning commands
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\metadef}[1]{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand#1{%
        \@ifstar{\csname s\string#1\endcsname}{\csname n\string#1\endcsname}%
    }%
    \edef\meta@def@name{\string#1}%
    \meta@def
}
\newcommand\meta@def[3][0]{%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname n\meta@def@name\endcsname[#1]{#2}%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname s\meta@def@name\endcsname[#1]{#3}%
}
\makeatother

% Creates \bkmrk, a command that easily sets a bookmark
\newcounter{bkmrk}
\newcommand{\bkmrk}[3]{%
    \addtocounter{bkmrk}{1}%
    \hypertarget{\thebkmrk}{#2}%
    \bookmark[dest=\thebkmrk, level=#1]{#3}%
}

% Creates \chapterplus, a command that, if not starred, acts like \chapter, and, if starred, acts like \chapter* but adds the entry to the bookmarks
\metadef{\chapterplus}[1]{\chapter{#1}}{\bkmrk{0}{\chapter*{#1}}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\chapterplus*{Chapter one}
\lipsum[1-2]

\chapterplus{Chapter two}
\lipsum[3-4]

\chapterplus*{Chapter three}
\lipsum[5-6]

\end{document}

It probably would be easy to just modify \chapter so that it does everything \chapter does, including setting a correct bookmark, besides numbering the chapter, and I could do that because I'm only using starred sectioning commands at the moment. The point is that I'm trying to produce a futurible solution since I'm setting a preamble that I plan to use again for future books of the same series and I may want to use numbered chapters in the future, so I prefer to go with \chapter* instead.

if you use only unnumbered sectioning commands, the easiest is to do \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1} and to use \chapter{xy} then you get bookmarks directly.

Yeah but as I mentioned I'd prefer to keep the unstarred version of those commands unmodified and find a way to bookmark the starred ones properly.

Well I do find your mix of starred and unstarred chapters quite suspicious. Generally the bookmarks are tight to the addcontentsline command which writes to entries. If you do not use that you have to do the bookmarks manually. Do it after the chapter. There is no need to create a target, chapter" is doing that.

@UlrikeFischer: I have set a manually-made TOC, in fact. Consider that this MWE represent a semplification of my problem. One of the reason I'm trying to solve this situation, for instance, is that many of the sections of my book are, in fact, generated by a custom command I was suggested to use in this other thread: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/712411/ifthenelse-atomic-proposition-not-behaving-as-expected-when-paired-with-fancy-f. This problem that I'm showing with chapters happens to every sections that end up at the beginning of a page.

If you want to add bookmarks automatically for chapter*, you only need to modify \@schapter (6 lines of code).

@JohnKormylo how do I do that?

You can also use etoolbox to edit the defnition.  If using twocolumn it looks better to put \pdfbookmark inside \@topnewpage, but you would have to change \@chapter too.
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{nameref}% redundant
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\@schapter#1{\pdfbookmark{#1}{#1}%
                 \if@twocolumn
                   \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
                 \else
                   \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
                   \@afterheading
                 \fi}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\chapter*{Chapter one}
\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter{Chapter two}
\lipsum[3-4]

\chapter*{Chapter three}
\lipsum[5-6]

\end{document}


This shows the etoolbox version.
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{nameref}% redundant
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@schapter}{\pdfbookmark{#1}{#1}}{}{FAILED\par}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Chapter one}
\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter{Chapter two}
\lipsum[3-4]

\chapter*{Chapter three}
\lipsum[5-6]

\end{document}


This solution works. I'm using the second variant in particular. But how can I do the same with \section*, \subsection* and \subsubsection*? I tried with @ssection and for some reason that doesn't work. Also I can't find any documention whatsoever about @schapter, hence I can't find what its equivalents are for other sectioning commands.

The source for \@schapter is found in book.cls.  However, \section etc. use \@startsection which is documented in latex2e.pdf.

Try \pretocmd{\@ssect}{\pdfbookmark{#5}{#5}}{}{FAILED\par}
